# Autocomplete all the fields of a form by selecting only the id - PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I briefly explain my goal, I have created for my client two different areas an area to select advertising facilities and an area where he registers his customers, now I would like to create the order area, where it will go inside to record in a single step form associating the values ​​of the advertising system field with those of a customer thus creating = association between a product and its customer.

I was seeing and I found many tutorials on how to create a form that can be autocompiled with a curtain but all the examples that I found auto fill only a part of the form.
How can I for example by selecting the id of a product that all the information of the latter are automatically autocompiled.

for example I have 6 fields
id

length

height

longitude

latitude

guy

by selecting only the id, the other 5 will be self-compiled directly

I'm trying with the selection of the fields generated by the database with the autocompilation but my visualization comes out completely unpacked I would like to have the user write in the form field and pull out a curtain

I put the code

```
<?php

session_start();

$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'ca2solution');

$query_string = "SELECT name FROM country WHERE name LIKE '%$q%'";

$query = mysqli_query($connection, $query_string);

?>

<form role="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="row setup-content-2" id="step-1">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold pl-0 my-4"><strong>Tipo di Impianto</strong></h3>
            <div id="searchBox" class="form-group md-form">

<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>

                <label for="yourEmail-2" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Email</label>
                <input id="searchBox" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['name'] ;?>" required="required" class="form-control validate">
                <div id="response"></div>

<?php } ?>




            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-mdb-color btn-rounded nextBtn-2 float-right" type="button">Next</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#searchBox").keyup(function () {
                    var query = $("#searchBox").val();

                    if (query.length > 0) {
                        $.ajax(
                            {
                                url: 'testtre.php',
                                method: 'POST',
                                data: {
                                    search: 1,
                                    q: query
                                },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $("#response").html(data);
                                },
                                dataType: 'text'
                            }
                        );
                    }
                });

                $(document).on('click', 'li', function () {
                    var country = $(this).text();
                    $("#searchBox").val(country);
                    $("#response").html("");
                });
            });
        </script>
```

image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNnHB.png)

Comment: Look at the links in my next comment to see how to form a question on SO that will help you get an answer

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Are you using AJAX/JSON to get the data to fill the fields? Or one form to select the ID an another to display the form?

Comment: i write the code in my question